# My Arduino Uno PS/2 to USB works only in serial monitor not in other Windows apps

Tags: arduino, keyboard, usb, uno, ps2

I'm a beginner in Arduino and recently programmed an Arduino Uno board with various PS/2 to USB converters. They work when typing in the Serial Monitor of Arduino IDE, but not in other programs such as Notepad.

[image]

How can I connect the board as HID keyboard for usual works with my PS/2 keyboard?

Thanks

**Note:** I used two versions of converters: [PS2Keyboard](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided is for code that only reads from a PS2 keyboard and prints what it reads to Serial.  It doesn't emulate a PS/2 keyboard in any way nor does it send any keystrokes to the computer in any way.  So you shouldn't expect to see output anywhere but in a terminal where you are reading that serial output.

If you want to create an actual HID device, then you will need one of the 32u4 Arduino boards like Leonardo that can serve as a USB host controller.

Comment: Thank you @Delta_G, your response was instructive for me as an Arduino beginner.

Comment: Please accept it as answered if it was helpful.  Please do not post identical question in multiple places in the future.  It's pretty much the same cast of characters in either place and it causes wasted time when someone is giving you an answer here that you already have there.